# Trying to json_agg multiple columns throws an error "No function matches the given name..."

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to use json_agg function on postgresql but it keeps throwing error saying

> ```
> ERROR:  function json_agg(character varying, character varying) does not exist
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> SQL state: 42883"
> ```

The problem comes when i am trying to agg multiple columns but not all.

i.e

```
SELECT json_agg(users.*) as users 
FROM users
```

works fine, same with single column query

i.e

```
SELECT json_agg(users.id) as users FROM users
```

but if I'm trying to agg multiple columns
i.e

```
SELECT json_agg(users.id, users.name, users.address) as users 
FROM users
```

it throws error shown above, why? Is that not possible or is there some specific syntax required?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`json_agg()` only takes a single parameter, not multiple parameters.

If you want to convert the whole row into a JSON and then aggregate that, pass the table reference:

```
SELECT json_agg(users) as users 
FROM users
```

If you only want some columns, use `json_build_object()`

```
SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('id', users.id, 'name', users.name)) as users 
FROM users
```

If you want most of the columns and just exclude a few, using `to_jsonb()` and removing the unwanted ones might be easier:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg((to_jsonb(users) - 'password')) as users 
FROM users
```

Comment: "*but not a complete row/record.*" - yet `json_agg(users)` and `json_agg(users.*)` do work?

Comment: @Bergi: ah, you are right. I misread the error message. Thanks. Corrected